# Load Activity Indicator at First before displaying UITableview

Tags: iphone

I using Facebook appication to my IPhone application. I used FBGraph api to get the all wall from facebook and I displayed the all data in the UITableview. I created UIActivityindicator.

But when i will click the UIButton, first all process  will done, after loading the data only, the view will displayed now. Now I need first activityindicator will displayed. after loading the data only the UITableview will displayed. How I will load the activity indicator first?

Answer (score 0):

Set the hidesWhenStopped property of your UIActivityIndicator to YES, and be sure it is not initialized to be animating.  In the handler for your UIButton tap, call something like:

```
[self.yourActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];
```

Later, when you have received all the data you desire, just call:

```
[self.yourActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
```

All of this assumes your UIActivityIndicatorView is initialized and added to your view hierarchy correctly.